# How can I make a component in AstroJS that renders paypal buttons?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, astrojs

I've adapated the client-side example from [Paypal's docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) and my code works fine if I add it directly to a page, but I want to create a reusable component, and when I try to do that and import the component, it just doesn't render. When I try to inspect the element in Chrome's dev tools, all I get is `<div class></div>`. Here is the code:

```
---
const clientId = import.meta.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID;
---

<!-- Replace "test" with your own sandbox Business account app client ID -->
  <script is:inline src={`https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}&currency=USD`}></script>
  <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  <script is:inline>
    paypal.Buttons({
      // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
      createOrder: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
              value: '77.44' // Can also reference a variable or function
            }
          }]
        });
      },
      // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
      onApprove: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
          // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
          console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
          const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
          alert(`Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}\n\nSee console for all available details`);
          // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
          // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
          // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
          // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
        });
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>
```

Comment: Such a component would only be usable once per page load, and without any other JS SDK instance being loaded on the page. You could try moving the script to the page's head to ensure it's only being loaded once; beyond that I don't know what the problem could be without seeing more details

Comment: @PrestonPHX I tried taking them both out of inline, then each one at a time, an neither worked, but I agree it's almost definitely in how, or more specifically when, the scripts are being run. I think I'll open an issue with astrojs on github. Also yes, I only need it to load once per page